# How to copy html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Hello i need to copy full html page that showing after login.

1. I have to build HttpWebRequest  that will fill user and password and will press homeLogin$connect
2. When i on the page i need i will copy it
   I get over the redirect page and i can copy only the first page

The (1) First step i did like this

```
myWebRespClass.PostString += "__REQUESTDIGEST=" + myWebRespClass.GetValueByID("__REQUESTDIGEST") + "&";
myWebRespClass.PostString += "__EVENTTARGET=homeLogin$connectLb&";
myWebRespClass.PostString += "__VIEWSTATE=" + myWebRespClass.GetValueByID("__VIEWSTATE") + "&";
myWebRespClass.PostString += "__EVENTVALIDATION=" + myWebRespClass.GetValueByID("__EVENTVALIDATION") + "&";
myWebRespClass.PostString += "homeLogin$txtUsername=" + strUser + "&";
myWebRespClass.PostString += "homeLogin$txtPassword=" + strPass;
myWebRespClass.CreatePostWebRequest("https://services.test.com/Page1/loginHome.aspx");
```

and after i tried to get to second page by my self because redirect did't work.

```
myWebRespClass.CreatePostWebRequest("https://services.test.com/Page2/IneedThisPAge.aspx");
```

Any one know easy way to do this?I stuck 3 days with this problem. help

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  There may be a simpler way if we know why.

Comment: I need to pull some data from page but i need to do login first for ex i have 100 users in my data base i need to pass the login page with all info that i have and then copy html and take data that i need and yes  it must be done programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the

```
private CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

and use them 
in all yours reuests

```
 postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                        postRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you could use the Google Screen Capture tool.

But if this must be done programmatically then there are code libraries like : http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/Capture-screenshot-of-website-in-c-sharp.html

Comment: No sory i need to save it in html or string i need to work with data that i have on this page and yes it must be done programmatically